# Flutter - Autoscroll to a CaroidrlSlider

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, vertical-scrolling, autoscroll

I am trying to enable autoscroll to a cards . it should scroll in a vertical .i want Autoscroll work without any user action.
and autoScroll in 5 second .

this is part pf my code i want to scroll:

```
 Container(
          width: 3000,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(height: 150.0),
              items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((i) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: greenHex),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, right: 10, left: 0, bottom: 8),
                            
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable autoPlay and set autoPlayInterval in Carousel Slider Options.

Example:

```
        CarouselSlider.builder(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            .
            .
            .
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 4),
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: and how can i set width for cards ?

Comment: Maybe viewportFraction, aspectRatio and height options are right for you.  'aspectRatio: 1,
 height: 500,
 viewportFraction: 0.8,'

Answer (score 0):

try below code hope its help to you. refer documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)  try yo set autoplay true

```
options: CarouselOptions(
      autoPlay: true,
    ),
```